# Saving SHA1 algorithm outputs to a text file

Tags: powershell, text, output, powershell-2.0, sha1

Morning,

I've got this powershell script as followed:

```
$zips = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\Powershell\Zip\' - Filter *.zip
$sha1 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider

foreach ($file in $zips) { 
$return = "" | Select Name, Hash

$return.name = $file.Name
$return.hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($sha1.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file.FullName)))

Write-Output $return 

[System.IO.File}::WriteAllText("C:\Users\X\Desktop\Info\"+ $_.Name + ".txt", $_.FullName)

}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to Exit"
```

So it calculates the SHA1 hash for all the zip files in the folder 'zip', I am trying to get it to save the hashes to a text file in the location \desktop\info\, with an individual text file for each zip file.

The hash is calculated with no problems, and it prints it within the powershell window, but all it does at the moment is create a singular text file with no data in it, and with no name.

What am I missing? I've tried using information from another script that does something very similar, but I cant seem to produce the same result.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For once, the content you are writing is the full filenamepath and not the `$return.hash` value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Users\X\Desktop\Info\"+$return.Name+".txt",$return.Hash)
```

Comment: I know it wasn't part of the original question, but if i wanted this to be added to existing text files with the same name, do you know how that would be done? I presume its just an -Append somewhere in there?

Comment: Worked it out, AppendAllText rather than WriteAllText. Cheers for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
[System.IO.File}::WriteAllText("C:\Users\X\Desktop\Info\"+ $_.Name + ".txt", $_.FullName)
```

try this:

```
$return.hash | Out-File "C:\Users\X\Desktop\Info\$($file.BaseName).txt"
```